# Firing Events from the Visualforce and Handling the Events in lightning components

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

If I have a visualforce page embedded in a lightning component.
How can I fire a lightning event in the visualforce page and then handle it in the lightning component?

In my Visualforce page i already included this function:

```
<apex:includeLightning />
<script>
     function fetchselectedvalue(){
                var myExternalEvent;
                myExternalEvent = $A.get("e.c:GetAddressInfos");
                myExternalEvent.setParams({"CityValue": document.getElementById('{!$Component.CityValue}').value});
                myExternalEvent.fire();
        }
</script>
```

Where GetAddressInfos is the name of my event.
But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a Lightning Component that wraps your VF page
- Use postMessage() to send a message from the VF page to the Lightning Component
- In the message handler of your wrapper component, create and fire your application event

See [this blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html) for details.